Does wagtail tag {% slugurl 'page' %} work with Wagtail-localize?
I'm building a website with Django, Wagtail and Wagtail Localize.
But when I'm load my website on "https://exemple.com/fr/"
the slugurl tags generates links like href="/en/about/"
I followed settings for urls.py :
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + i18n_patterns(
    path("search/", search_views.search, name="search"),
    path("", include(wagtail_urls)),
)

I also added middleware and others setting like LANGUAGES. Page are correctly translated and accessible with urls.
The language code is detected because tag like {% if LANGUAGE_CODE == "fr" %} is working but this slugurl never work and always display "/en/about/" :
<a href="{% slugurl 'about' %}" class="nav-links">about</a>

Navigation isn't very fluid, because when you access a page you have to reselect the language each time.
Is slugurl supposed to work with Wagtail-localize?

slugurl will always only return the first page that matches the slug - that slug might also be repeated on each locale, so it needs some care.
I use a custom templatetag to return the localised page for the first match:
@register.simple_tag()
def trans_page_from_slug(slug, specific=False):
    try:
        if specific:
            return Page.objects.live().filter(slug=slug).first().specific.localized
        else:
            return Page.objects.live().filter(slug=slug).first().localized
    except:
        return Page.objects.none()

So even if your French page slug is something like 'a-propos', the templatetag will return the correct translated page for the slug 'about'.
I guess if you just want the url back, you could use:
@register.filter()
def localised_slugurl(slug):
    try:
        return Page.objects.live().filter(slug=slug).first().localized.url
    except:
        return ''

Then your nav link is:
<a href="{{ 'about'|localised_slugurl }}" class="nav-links">about</a>

That won't change your 'about' label though. For that, you could use the trans_page_from_slug templatetag to return the page, then access the url and title attributes in your link:
{% trans_page_from_slug "about" as link %}
<a href="{{ link.url }}" class="nav-links">{{ link.title }}</a>

If your page titles are too long for the nav menu, add an optional menu_title field to your page models and use that where needed. Default to title so you always have a value:
{{ link.menu_title|default:link.title }}

Just make sure you're returning the specific page from the templatetag if you do this as the base Page model won't include your custom field.

Ok thanks I'm testing "localised_slugurl" and it's working very well ! for slugurl I don't know why it's not working because all my slug are the same for each language

Ok, great! I'm fairly sure slugurl will match the first instance of the slug it finds, so if it exists in the default locale, it'll find that first.
